# JSON.parse won't convert JSON string into object in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm building a role based login for an angular app and when you first enter your credentials a session object is sent back with a bunch of properties, including an array of roles the user can select to sign in as. When the user selects the radio button for the corresponding role they want to be signed in as, e.g. "Administrator", I use `ng-model' to update`$scope.model.selected` to whatever object they chose.

However, at some point in the UI `$scope.model` gets parsed into a string when I need it to be a javascript object. In short, I'm trying to convert my model back to an object and I can't get `JSON.parse($scope.model)` to work.

Here's my controller:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
      $http
        .post(app.api.root + 'session-tokens', $scope.user)
        .then(
          // SUCCESS
          function (response) {
            $scope.model = { selected: response.data.results.roles[0] };
            $scope.results = response.data.results;
            $scope.isCorrect = true;
            $scope.welcome = 'Welcome, ' + $scope.user.username + '!';

            // redirect after login -- need to change this to a profile page
            // $location.path('/patients/22');
            $scope.login = function() {
              $scope.model = JSON.parse($scope.model);
              authSvc.user({
                id: response.data.results.userId,
                token: $scope.model.selected.token,
                role: $scope.model.selected.roleName,
                providerName: $scope.model.selected.providerName,
                username: $scope.user.username,
                isAuthenticated: true
              });
              $scope.user = authSvc.user();
              console.log(typeof $scope.model.selected);
            };
          }
};
```

The function that I want to do the conversion is `$scope.login()`, which fires after the user selects a role and clicks login.

Any idea how I can get this to work? And I don't think I'm on a new enough version of angular to use `angular.fromJson`.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's the error I get in the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
at Object.parse (native)
at Scope.$scope.login (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:4000/$js/jquery.js:336:5), <anonymous>:32:39)
at http://localhost:4000/$js/angular.js:10288:21
at http://localhost:4000/$js/angular.js:18086:17
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:4000/$js/angular.js:12045:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:4000/$js/angular.js:12145:23)
at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4000/$js/angular.js:18085:21)
at HTMLFormElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:4000/$js/jquery.js:4371:9)
at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:4000/$js/jquery.js:4057:28)
```

**EDIT**

So `$scope.model` does actually return an object, but `$scope.model.selected` returns a json string, and I need it to be an object.

The string returned is:

`{"roleName":"Group Provider","providerId":100,"providerName":"TestProvider","token":"XXX"}`

**CONSOLE.LOGS**

```
console.log(response.data.results):
Object {userId: 3, roles: Array[2]}

console.log(response.data.results.roles[0]):
Object {roleName: "Administrator", providerId: 2, providerName: "TestLastNAme, Test", token: "xxx", $$hashKey: "0fL"}

console.log($scope.model):
Object {selected: "{"roleName":"Group Provider","providerId…Nn0.lwB6AggcMkvH_LcQzpUdLlbk3XBHTGBqCd8K07HBIfo"}"}

console.log($scope.model.selected):
{"roleName":"Group Provider","providerId":237,"providerName":"TestProvider","token":"xxx"} 

console.dir($scope.model):
Object
    selected: "{"roleName":"Insurance Group Provider","providerId":237,"providerName":"TestProvider","token":"xxx"}"
    __proto__: Object
```

Comment: What is the text of `$scope.model`?  (My guess: an error message.)

Comment: I added another edit.

Comment: What is the exact json string?

Comment: That error occurs when you attempt to use `JSON.parse()` on an object. Are you sure you need to be using `JSON.parse()` at all?

Comment: I added the string. Yes...I need the properties from the string I added above in object form.

Comment: The given string is unserialized without any issues `JSON.parse('{"roleName":"Group Provider","providerId":100,"providerName":"TestProvider","token":"XXX"}')`. Seems like your assumption about your data is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of that and it turns out the problem was I was using `value="{{model}}"` on the radio buttons instead of angular's `ng-value="model"`. `value=` will parse the object into a string while `ng-value` will keep it as an object.

Comment: To clarify, that's because the result of `{{ }}` is the evaluation of the expression within, no matter where you use it. In your case that would result in a string containing the contents of the variable model. Good job finding the solution! If we had seen your HTML it would've been obvious, but hindsight is 20/20.

Answer (score 1):

That error occurs when you attempt to use JSON.parse() on an object.

Comment: The problem is that somehow it's getting converted to a string when the vaue changes in the view. When I initially set $scope.model it is an object, so I dont need to parse that; I need to parse the new model being saved in its place.

Comment: `console.log(response.data.results);` and `console.log(response.data.results.roles[0]);` and `console.log($scope.model);` and `console.log($scope.model.selected);`

Comment: you're definitely trying to use `JSON.parse()` on an object. we can figure out why with some logging.

Comment: sorry, try `console.dir($scope.model);` for me as well.